# copy char* in shared memory boost

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I want to know if I can write in a file (shared memory with boost) a char*. I have create a Template, and works fine with "int" and "string", but with char*, I can access to them in memory, when I am executing the program, but the data is not stored in the file afterwards as happens with ints and strings.

The representative piece of the code would be:  (T would be char*)

```
//DECLARATIONS
MyMap *mymap;
managed_mapped_file seg = managed_mapped_file(open_or_create, tableName, tablesize);
mymap = seg->find_or_construct<MyMap>("MyMap")      //object name
            (std::less<T>() //first  constructor parameter
            ,*alloc_inst);    //second constructor parameter

//THE METHOD TO ADD THE ENTRIES
template<class T>
void ShareDB<T>::add_ref_info_to_db (const T &Symbol_Index , const std::string &a_info){

MyMap::iterator res =  mymap->find(Symbol_Index);

mymap->insert(std::pair<const T, shared_string>(Symbol_Index, localSymbol));
```

so I call to the Template like that:

```
ShareDB <char *> ex;
ex.openDB(dataBaseName,"TestMutex", 196608, true);
ex.add_ref_info_to_db (a,ex.RefInfoRecord);
```

Maybe it is just that I can not write pointers...I am not sure...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using a map with a pointer as the key, this does not make sense. Rather than `char*` as the key, use `std::string` as the key to your map. Also, without seeing what your `MyMap::insert()` function does with the `char*` it's difficult to tell what is going wrong...

Comment: I agree with Nim more relevant code would help, the definition of insert(), the code that is actually writing the value, any copying or assignment of Symbol_Index, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `template<class T>` consider `template<typename T>` ... however i would simply use `std::string` unless you must support `char *` specifically.

Comment: I have to support char *...the only problem is that it seems that at the end it does not write the char* in memory, the rest of the behavoir is fine...any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try changing the template to use typename?  While generally they are the same in some compilers using typename works better with integral types that are not user defined objects such as int, double, char ... Do you get any output at all?  Unexpected output other than the characters desired could be a clue as to what is actually happening.